# '/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npPluginTest.so' is not an ELF executable for sh

Tags: linux, elf

I have created NPAPI plugin, which is workig fine on linux where I have created the .so file but when I deployed this plugin on our production device where we have linux environment with limited resources(due to performance constraints) , following error is thrown

'/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npPluginTest.so' is not an ELF executable for sh

FYI:so file created on 32bit linux box.

how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you FTP it over in binary mode?

Comment: I have nfs server so simply copied it and paste it to shared folder and  deployed it using cp command. is there any issue with this process?

Comment: Are you trying to run this on 64 bit system. the 32 bit so file . you can read the elf header using # readelf -h '/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npPluginTest.so and read the field Class: field

Comment: I am running this on 32 bit system, the result ofELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xbff0

Answer (score 0):

I build the plugin using wrong toolchain/compiler. instead of Machine: Intel 80386 it should Machine: ST40. I build my shared library on ST GCC compiler.Now my NAPI Plugin is working fine.
Thanks for your suggestions.